# I do not want to upgrade jetpack compose from RC to Alpha

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-lint

... but also I do not have to see that lint warning.
It suggest to upgrade from 1.3 RC to 1.4 Alpha.

What would you suggest to do?

Comment: 1.3.0 stable came out on Monday, so perhaps you could update to that.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the warning for a specific dependency, you can use the **noinspection** annotation just above the line that causes the warning. Like this:

```
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'compose.....'
```

You can also check how to [disable linting](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#gradle) for whole gradle files or scopes